# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException in update

Tags: php, laravel

When I click on update button I get next error:

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
        No message

For update I have next routes:

```
Route::post('edit/user/{id}','UsersController@update');
Route::get('edit/user/{id}','UsersController@edit');
```

As you see, I use post method for update.

My controller code:

```
public function edit($id){
            $user = User::where('id',$id)
            ->first();
            return view('user.edit', compact('user','id'));
        }

        public function update(Request $request, $id){
            $user = new User();
            $data_user = $this->validate($request,$rules_user);
            $data_user['id'] = $id;
            $user->updateUser($data_user);
            return redirect('/users');
        }
```

My update.blade.php code:

```
   @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div><br />
@endif
    <div class="row">
    <form method="post" action="{{action('UsersController@update', $id)}}" >
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
        <div class="form-group">
       <input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token" /> 
            <label for="name">User name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value={{$user->name}} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: here `value={{$user->name}}` should be `value="{{$user->name}}" ` otherewise it will display only one word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your action attribute you specified a direct call to the controller without going to the route URI. Therefore address the action attribute to this

```
<form method="post" action="edit/user/{{$id}}" >
```

It will go through the route and validates the CSRF then proceeds to the request

Comment: I am new to laravel can you please explain me  more about this because i am getting same error  again and again when request type is post  and for get it is working.

Comment: Try using this                                                                                               `<form method="post" action="{{url('/edit/user',$id)}}">`

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be 
Put instead of post

```
Route::put('edit/user/{id}','UsersController@update’)
```

Comment: I change route as your write, but I have same error. What can I else do?